# Index with only line numbers and no page numbers ? (edit)

Tags: page-numbering, indexing, line-numbering, imakeidx, reledmac

**EDIT** I don't konw if I have the right to do that, and I apologize if I don't, but I have change my previous post in order to refocus the questions and to be clearer.

I have been trying for several hours (months) to find everything about the customization of indices that would match what I would like my indexes to be, but failed. As you can see, I am using reledmac and imakeidx. I know some stuff can be done with the .ist files, but I haven't been able to find what could work for my issues.

I also tried playing with the memoir package (I am still not able to only have the line numbers) and the glossaries package (Even more difficult, since I can't have the line numbers and can't do two glossaries).

So here it is anyway :

- I would like to get rid of the page number in order to keep only the line number.
- And, for later, to be able to have justified entries in the indexes, especially if there are two columns.

Here is an exemple:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
\Xnonbreakableafternumber
\Xlemmaseparator{:}
\Xparafootsep{$\parallel$}

\numberpstarttrue

\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}
\pagestyle{plain}

\makeindex[options=-s mystyle.ist, name=np, columns=1, title=Index des noms propres]
\makeindex[options=-s mystyle.ist, name=glo, columns=1, title=Glossaire] 
\indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section,noclearpage}

\begin{filecontents*}{mystyle.ist}
delim_0 ", "
delim_1 " "
delim_2 " "
delim_n ", "
delim_t "."
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix " {\\bfseries\\large\\hfill "
heading_suffix " \\hfill}\\nopagebreak\n "
\end{filecontents*}

\mainmatter

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\linenumincrement{4}
\firstlinenum{0}
\setstanzaindents{2,0}
\setcounter{stanzaindentsrepetition}{1}
\AtEveryStopStanza{\bigbreak}
\stanza
\hspace{0.5cm} BlaBlaBla.&
Jean\edindex[np]{Jean@Jean~: personnage biblique} Blablabla&
Blablablabla&
Blablabla montagne\edindex[glo]{montagne@montagne~: <<~hauteur terreste~>>}.\&
\endnumbering

\chapter*{Annexes}
\indexprologue{Nous relevons ici les noms communs.\bigbreak}
\printindex[glo]
\indexprologue{Nous relevons ici les noms propres.\bigbreak}
\printindex[np]
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: that is most related to .ist files than to reledmac/indextools. I will let other people answer, as I am not a specialiste of this problem.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks anyway. Should I change the flags then ?

Comment: do what you want.

Comment: If you a no answer is two days, you can send me a mail, I will look for it.

Answer (score 1):

After talking with Maïeul, he gave me the answer regarding the indexation on the line number only. Here is the code that needs to be added in the preamble.
I hope Mr. Maïeul don't mind me posting it, since I think it may help others with their critical edition as well.

```
\renewcommand{\thepageline}{%
     \xlineref{\edindexlab\thelabidx}% }
```

I tested it and it works perfectly !